# sql statement error while connecting with db2 using eclipse juno

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

```
String searchQuery = "select * from REAL MADR.USERS where username='"
                        + username
                        + "' AND password='"
                        + password
                        + "'";
```

This is my search string where real madr is  my schema name in db2 while users is the database name.

It gives me the following error:

```
'com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-10, SQLSTATE=42603, SQLERRMC=', DRIVER=3.59.81'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `from` clause.

Do you mean this?

```
 select * from REALMADR.USER
```

or this?

```
 select * from REAL.MADR.USER
```

or this?

```
 select * from "REAL MADR".USER
```

or perhaps something else along these lines?